# How to write CC/BCC in SMTP in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net

I am finding it difficult to CC or BCC user using SMTP. The message to the CC or BCC user is never received. I have tried many conjugations. I now have the following, which also fails to work:

```
 Dim CC As MailAddress = New MailAddress("assistant@mypage.com")
 Dim Bcc As MailAddress = New MailAddress(user_email)

 myMessage.From = New MailAddress(user_email) 'User's email
 myMessage.To.Add(New MailAddress("info@mypage.com")) 'Webmaster
 'myMessage.CC.Add(New MailAddress("assistant@mypage.com")) 'Asst Webmaster

 myMessage.CC.Add(CC)
 myMessage.Bcc.Add(Bcc)
```

What should I be coding, please?. The Webmaster himself DOES receive his copy of the sender's message.

Comment: Have you determined that this is definitely a problem with `CC` and `Bcc`?  For instance, if you switch the addresses in `To` and `CC`, which address(es) receives the email then?  If it's still the same address that receives the message then it would appear to be an issue with the email addresses themselves and not the fact that they're added to `CC` or `Bcc`.

Comment: I can't switch the addresses in To and CC because the CC aspect does not work. It is as if CC and BCC are ignored altogether. Also, It cannot be the addresses themselves because they are valid Outlook and Hotmail addresses.

Comment: All you know is the result that you get. You're making an assumption as to the cause. That assumption may or may not be valid.  You CAN switch the addresses. It's a simple code change.  Make it. Run it. See what the outcome is. That will provide evidence to determine whether your assumption is correct or not.

Comment: If you are adding address 1 to the `To` list and address 2 to the `CC` list and the message arrives only at address 1 then it may be an issue with the `CC` functionality or with address 2. If you switch the addresses and the message only arrives at address 2 then it is likely an issue with the `CC` functionality but if it arrives only at address 1 then it is like an issue with address 2. This is called testing and it's part of software development.  Don't post questions here without having done this sort of testing first.

Comment: I have swapped the 2 emails about so that the previous CC became the Webmaster, and the Webmaster became the CC using
Dim CC As MailAddress = New MailAddress("oldWebmasterEmail")
myMessage.CC.Add(New MailAddress("oldWebmasterEmail"))
The person who is now CC, the previous Webmaster, is copied in to the message in that person's inbox. The other 
person's email generates a server error: No such user here.

Comment: So if the web master's email address is added to the `CC` list and a message is indeed received at that address then clearly it is not an issue with the `CC` list. If the other person's email address generates an error when added to the `To` list then clearly there is an issue with that person's email address, so it won't work when added to the `CC` list either.

Comment: So it seems, but that other person's email address is my own Microsoft email that is daily used.Does the server error suggest that I need to include that address in the acceptable email addresses with my Web hosting service, because it cannot mean that my own address is invalid? Thanks

Comment: Is it the 'norm' that I would set up the CC email address as 'acceptable', on the SMTP server of my Web hosting service through the control panel? Maybe because I have not already done that, the SMTP server is questioning the validity of the CC email address and not delivering the message?

Comment: That's a different question and one that you can test for yourself. I don't know the answer but, if I wanted to know, I'd try that and see whether it fixed the issue.